# Como fazer update em uma tabela usando mysql c# e um método?

Tags: c#, mysql

É possível utilizar um método ou classe que utilize campos da tabela para fazer um update nesta mesma tabela?

Por exemplo: atualizar campo1 de registro 1 com f(campo2 de registro1), campo1 de resgistro 2 com f(campo2 de registro2), etc...

```
reg|campo1|campo2
1    f(x)   x 
2    f(y)   y
```

Código seria algo como:

```
string conectaBanco = "server = localhost; port = 3306; User Id = root; 
database=mysql; password=";
MySqlConnection objcon = new MySqlConnection(conectaBanco);
objcon.Open();

MySqlCommand objCmd = new MySqlCommand("tabela_A set campo1=?", objcon);
objCmd.Parameters.Add("@campo1", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = 
metodo_qualquer(param1);
objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Sendo que o `metodo_qualquer()` é executado a cada registro que se faz o update

Um exempo mais didático: 
Um campo da tabela DataNota (campo1) contem as respostas de um aluno a um teste (ACDEB) e em outro (campo2) há o gabarito (CCDAE). O campo3 conterá o número de acertos. Então preciso fazer um update no campo3 com a informação do número de acertos que será o resultado do tratamento dos campos 1 e 2. Para isto há um método (calcAcertos) que, dados campo1 e campo2, calcula o número de acertos tratando as strings “ACDEB” e ”CCDAE”. Assim sendo é necessário fazer:
update DataNota set campo3=calcAcertos(campo1, campo2)

Campo1 = ACDEB
Campo2 = CCDAE
Acertos = 2
Campo3 = 2

Comment: Está meio dificil de entender a sua pergunta... principalmente no exemplo, teria como deixar mais claro?

Comment: Você pode utilizar os mesmos campo no update sim: `update tabela_A set campo1= campo2 + campo2 where reg = ?;` (exemplo somando os campos, vai saber qq é esse f(x))